# How to get count as 0 for non-existing values in a table using in for a sub query

Tags: mysql

I need help for writing the correct query. We have a survey db where we have OfferedAnswers table for a question which has mapping of question_id and answer_id.

OfferedAnswers:

```
-----------------------
answer_id   | question_id
-----------------------
1           |  1
-----------------------
2           |  1
-----------------------
3           |  1
-----------------------
4           |  1
-----------------------
```

Another is FeedbackQuestionAnswer table which records response for question_id and answer_id as voted by the users.

FeedbackQuestionAnswer :

```
-----------------------
question_id   | answer_id
-----------------------
1             |  1
-----------------------
1             |  2
-----------------------
1             |  1
-----------------------


 select    FeedbackQuestionAnswer.answer_Id, 
           count(FeedbackQuestionAnswer.answer_Id) as count 
           from dEbill.FeedbackQuestionAnswer  
           where FeedbackQuestionAnswer.answer_Id in
           (select answer_Id 
                   from dEbill.OfferedAnswers 
                   where question_Id = 1)
           group by FeedbackQuestionAnswer.answer_Id
```

In above case the output is :

```
    -----------------------
    answer_id   | count
    -----------------------
    1           |  2
    -----------------------
    2           |  1
    -----------------------
```

whereas I want :

```
    -----------------------
    answer_id   | count
    -----------------------
    1           |  2
    -----------------------
    2           |  1
    -----------------------
    3           |  0
    -----------------------
    4           |  0
    -----------------------
```

I tried using OfferedAnswer.answer_Id instead of FeedbackQuestionAnswer.answer_Id but got a scope error.
I also tried right join but no success.

Comment: shall we used  Coalesce

Comment: I believe an outer join is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a left join, and count the non NULL entries in the second table:

```
SELECT
    t1.answer_id,
    COUNT(t2.answer_id) AS count
FROM OfferedAnswers t1
LEFT JOIN FeedbackQuestionAnswer t2
    ON t1.answer_id = t2.answer_id
WHERE
    t1.question_id = 1
GROUP BY
    t1.answer_id
ORDER BY
    t1.answer_id;
```

[image: screen capture of query output]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you Tim. We tried your solution. It seems you have missed t1.question_Id = 1 condition. So   we tried 

SELECT
    t1.answer_id,
    COUNT(t2.answer_id) AS count
FROM OfferedAnswers t1
LEFT JOIN FeedbackQuestionAnswer t2
    ON t1.answer_id = t2.answer_id and t1.question_Id = 1 
GROUP BY
    t1.answer_id
but no success it only gets 2 rows for answer_id 1 and answer_id 2

Comment: basically i added t1.question_Id = 1 to the join condition

Comment: @j10 Sorry, I guess I missed that.  Minor change though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :  While creating the question I forgot to add timestamp. Can you please check here : http://rextester.com/EHKB10523

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I got it. I added the 2 new conditions to the 'On' Clause

Comment: @j10 Good on you.  Ping me if you have further questions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Thank you. Just curious to know for the question in this post : Why the t1.question_id = 1 condition does not yield the expected result when used in the 'on' clause; but yields expected result when put as a separate condition in the 'where' clause.

Comment: @j10 Actually, for the sample data you gave, it doesn't matter because there is only 1 question_id.  In general, if you move the condition to the `ON` clause, you won't remove any records based on the `question_id`.  What you would then get, would be potentially _every_ question, but questions which are not 1 would have `NULL` everywhere for the joined columns.